# Getting ERROR Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements

Tags: angular8, angular-components

I am getting error

```
"ERROR Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
at t.selectRootElement (angular8-demo.js:3)
at e.create (angular8-demo.js:3)
at t.bootstrap (angular8-demo.js:3)
at angular8-demo.js:3
at Array.forEach ()
at t._moduleDoBootstrap (angular8-demo.js:3)
at angular8-demo.js:3
at t.invoke (angular8-demo.js:2)
at Object.onInvoke (angular8-demo.js:3)
at t.invoke (angular8-demo.js:2) "
```

while importing angular 8 component to an external html file.Also i had done with exporting an individual component to and external html page, but the component was not fully loaded. some of its fields are missing.

Answer (score 0):

**app-root** is the selector of the **app.componant.html** file

please check this selector is available in App.Component.ts file as shown below :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

This selector gets called from the index.html file as below

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

And **AppComponent** should be declared in App.Module.ts file and added in the bootstrap as shown below

```
     declarations: [   
        AppComponent,    
      ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
```

Please check have you declared the AppComponent in App.Module.ts file.